# sort array in python3 using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, numpy

I have an numpy array with shape (N, 9).

for example:

```
[[1579.0, 483.0, 1949.0, 407.0, 1959.0, 454.0, 1589.0, 531.0, 0.33], 
 [1613.0, 1115.0, 1995.0, 1093.0, 1998.0, 1137.0, 1616.0, 1159.0, 0.16],   
 [904.0, 1417.0, 1068.0, 1420.0, 1067.0, 1461.0, 904.0, 1458.0, 0.31], 
 [1583.0, 479.0, 1950.0, 401.0, 1961.0, 452.0, 1593.0, 530.0, 0.33], 
 [1604.0, 482.0, 1943.0, 407.0, 1954.0, 454.0, 1614.0, 530.0, 0.13], 
 [908.0, 1418.0, 1064.0, 1421.0, 1064.0, 1458.0, 907.0, 1456.0, 0.21]]
```

I want to sort this array based on the first number in each line. in other word based on the firs number from the second dimension.

the result should be::

```
[[904.0, 1417.0, 1068.0, 1420.0, 1067.0, 1461.0, 904.0, 1458.0, 0.31],
 [908.0, 1418.0, 1064.0, 1421.0, 1064.0, 1458.0, 907.0, 1456.0, 0.21]
 [1579.0, 483.0, 1949.0, 407.0, 1959.0, 454.0, 1589.0, 531.0, 0.33], 
 [1583.0, 479.0, 1950.0, 401.0, 1961.0, 452.0, 1593.0, 530.0, 0.33],
 [1604.0, 482.0, 1943.0, 407.0, 1954.0, 454.0, 1614.0, 530.0, 0.13],
 [1613.0, 1115.0, 1995.0, 1093.0, 1998.0, 1137.0, 1616.0, 1159.0, 0.16]   
 ]
```

how could I do this in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With NumPy, you can use `argsort` with the first column:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array(L)
res = A[A[:, 0].argsort()]
```

With a list, you can use `sorted` with `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = sorted(L, key=itemgetter(0))

print(res)

[[904.0, 1417.0, 1068.0, 1420.0, 1067.0, 1461.0, 904.0, 1458.0, 0.31],
 [908.0, 1418.0, 1064.0, 1421.0, 1064.0, 1458.0, 907.0, 1456.0, 0.21],
 [1579.0, 483.0, 1949.0, 407.0, 1959.0, 454.0, 1589.0, 531.0, 0.33],
 [1583.0, 479.0, 1950.0, 401.0, 1961.0, 452.0, 1593.0, 530.0, 0.33],
 [1604.0, 482.0, 1943.0, 407.0, 1954.0, 454.0, 1614.0, 530.0, 0.13],
 [1613.0, 1115.0, 1995.0, 1093.0, 1998.0, 1137.0, 1616.0, 1159.0, 0.16]]
```